# Criar uma associação chave/valores a partir de dados informados pelo usuário

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

**8) Escreva um algoritmo capaz de receber uma quantidade variável de parâmetros que estejam associados a uma chave. Em seguida, imprima na tela o nome da chave e o respectivo valor:**

```
def func_varios_parametros_dic(**dicionario):
    print(dicionario)

lista_k = []
lista_v = []
x = 0

while True:
    lista_k.append(input("Informe a chave[q em ambos p/ sair]: "))
    lista_v.append(input("Informe o valor[q em ambos p/ sair]: "))
    if (lista_k[x] != 'q' and lista_v[x] != 'q'):
        func_varios_parametros_dic(**dict(zip(lista_k, lista_v)))
        x += 1
    else:
        break
```

Funciona normal, porém se eu por exemplo digito **r** na ***chave*** e **3** no ***valor***, a saída é assim:

> {'r': '3'}

e se depois digito **r** novamente na ***chave*** e **5** no ***valor***, a saída fica assim:

> {'r': '5'}

sendo que o que eu quero, é que fique assim:

> {'r': '3', 'r': '5'}

ou seja, se digito uma ***chave*** repetida, no caso a letra **r**, a mesma é sobrescrita juntamente com seu ***valor*** **5**. Não estou sabendo o pq de não ser impresso na tela o par ***chave/valor*** mesmo sendo repetidos.

Comment: O resultado `{'r': '3', 'r': '5'}` não será possível. O dicionário é um mapa que define uma relação 1:1 entre chave/valor. Não há como a mesma chave possuir dois valores. No máximo o que você pode fazer é algo como `{'r': ['3', '5']}`, onde o valor é uma lista de valores informados pelo usuário.

Comment: Só pensar no conceito de **chave**, que é único. por isso voce esta tendo esse problema usando o dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O dicionário define uma relação injetora entre as chaves e os valores. Na prática, isso implica que a chave de um dicionário deve ser única e relacionada à apenas um valor (o contrário não é válido, pois um valor pode estar associado a mais de uma chave).

Vide [documentação oficial da linguagem](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> *It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, **with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)**. A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way dictionaries are written on output.*

Portanto, a saída `{'r': '3', 'r': '5'}` que você deseja não é possível obter - não com dicionário padrão, pelo menos. Mas como o enunciado não pede que a chave seja duplicada, apenas que seja possível associar múltiplos valores a uma chave, você pode criar uma lista para armazenar os valores.

Também, quanto a sua solução, acho um pouco desconfortável para o usuário ter que entrar com a chave toda vez que deseja inserir um novo valor. Você pode aqui definir dois laços de repetição para ler indefinidamente os valores de cada chave.

```
dicionario = {}

while True:
    chave = input('Entre com a chave [enter para sair]: ')
    if not chave:
        break
    if chave not in dicionario:
        dicionario[chave] = []
    while True:
        valor = input(f'Entre com o valor para a chave {chave} [enter para sair]: ')
        if not valor:
            break
        dicionario[chave].append(valor)

print('Seu dicionário final é:')
print(dicionario)
```

Assim, ficaria:

```
Entre com a chave [enter para sair]:  a
Entre com o valor para a chave a [enter para sair]:  1
Entre com o valor para a chave a [enter para sair]:  2
Entre com o valor para a chave a [enter para sair]:  
Entre com a chave [enter para sair]:  b
Entre com o valor para a chave b [enter para sair]:  1
Entre com o valor para a chave b [enter para sair]:  
Entre com a chave [enter para sair]:  
Seu dicionário final é:
{'a': ['1', '2'], 'b': ['1']}
```

Você pode, ainda, utilizar algumas variações do dicionário, como [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) para definir o tipo padrão do valor caso ele não exista no dicionário.

> Perceba que utilizei o próprio <kbd>Enter</kbd> para terminar cada laço pois, provavelmente, o par chave/valor `{'q': 'q'}` seja perfeitamente válido dentro do dicionário.